# Одномерные массивы

Tags: java

Помогите решить задачу. Даны два массива A и B одинакового размера N. Сформировать новый массив C того же размера, каждый элемент которого равен максимальному из элементов массивов A и B с тем же индексом.

Пример задачи:

Введите N: 6

Введите A: 1 -2 3 0 4 2

Введите B: -2 5 1 3 4 7

Ответ:

Массив C: 1 5 3 3 4 7

```
int n = in.nextInt();  
int a[] = new int[n];  
int b[] = new int[n];    
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){    
    System.out.printf("a[%d]: %n",i);  
    a[i]=in.nextInt();  
}
for (int k=0; k<n; k++){  
    System.out.printf("‚ b[%d]: %n",k);  
    b[k]=in.nextInt();   
}
```

Я не знаю как сформировать новый массив C того же размера, каждый элемент которого равен максимальному из элементов массивов A и B с тем же индексом.

Comment: StackOverflow не предназначен для решения учебных заданий за других. Но сообщество с радостью вам поможет, если у вас конкретная проблема в написанном вами коде.

Comment: Вы пробовали писать код формирования массива С? Если нет, то попробуйте. Если да, то добавьте его в ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю , что за класс `in` у вас ..

```
 int n = Random.nextInt();  
 int a[] = new int[n];  
 int b[] = new int[n];  
 int c[] = new int[n];  

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){    
   a[i] = Random.nextInt();
   b[i] = Random.nextInt();
   c[i] = a[i] > b[i] ? a[i] : b[i];  
 }
```

Comment: Скорее всего in - это инстанс класса Scanner